# Selenium 3.14.0+ ClassCast Exception for Actions.movetoElement after upgrading selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have upgraded selenium to latest version 3.14.0, and found that the following method is throwing a class cast exception

new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.prahs.utils.logger.EventWebDriver$EventFiringWebElement cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.Locatable

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this?  I just ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way,

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement("Web Element").click().perform();
```

Build is for different purpose,

[image]

Reference Link : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: This didn't fix the missing library.  Actions is still unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

You may using different versions Selenium for api.

It is likely related to this?

[Selenium Actions Class cannot be resolved in selenium version greater then 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027324/selenium-actions-class-cannot-be-resolved-in-selenium-version-greater-then-3-1/52993740?noredirect=1#comment92899155_52993740)